# mysql sorting of version numbers

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have values like:

```
1.1.2 
9.1 
2.2
4
1.2.3.4
3.2.14
3.2.1.4.2
.....
```

I need to sort those values using mysql. The data type for this one is varbinary(300).

The desired output will be like:

```
1.1.2
1.2.3.4
2.2
3.2.1.4.2
3.2.14
4
9.1
```

The Query is:

```
select version_number from table order by version_number asc
```

it does not give the correct sorting order.

The desired output of this is:

```
1.1.2
1.2.3.4
2.2
3.2.1.4.2
3.2.14 
4
9.1
```

The version numbers are up to 20 digits (like 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.2.34) and more also. There is no particular max size and the standard version is just like above mentioned.

Comment: What type are you storing these as?

Comment: In ascending order, which do you expect to come first `1.2.13` or `1.2.2`?

Comment: Can you post your output and point out the issue (actual vs. desired)?

Comment: Mostly you store this version_number in Varchar2, so you can't perform sorting like this.

Comment: Is there a maximum known size of each component? Can you store a standardized version (such as `011.023.005` instead of `11.23.5`) in a separate column just for sorting purposes?

Answer (score 55):

Try abusing the `INET_ATON` function to do the sorting like so:

```
SELECT version_number FROM table ORDER BY INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(version_number,'.0.0.0'),'.',4))
```

This trick was originally posted on the [mysql mailing list](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/183349), so many thanks to the original poster, Michael Stassen!

Here's what he had to say:

> If each part is no larger than 255, you can leverage INET_ATON() to do 
>   what you want (up to the 4th part).  The trick is making each of these 
>   look like an IP first by using CONCAT to add '0.0.0' to make sure every 
>   row has at least 4 parts, then SUBSTRING_INDEX to pull out just the 
>   first 4 parts.
>
> Now, I must point out that because we are sorting on a function of the 
>   column, rather than on the column itself, we cannot use an index on the 
>   column to help with the sort.  In other words, the sorting will be 
>   relatively slow.

In the latter case, he recommends a solution similar to the one posted by @spanky (separate columns).

Comment: also works with single version numbers (where 0.9 < 0.10)

Comment: Thanks! Also works with "group by version_number order by INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(version_number,'.0.0.0'),'.',4)) desc"

Answer (score 7):

I would store it in three separate columns, one for each part of the version number.

Make each column a TINYINT and even create an index across the 3 columns. That should make things simple.

Then you can do:
`select CONCAT(v1,'.',v2,'.',v3) AS version_number FROM table ORDER BY v1 asc, v2 asc, v3 asc`

Comment: That's going to get pretty horrendous with 20 components in the version number.

Comment: you could replicate your versions as a nested set model in that case, so you can make it grow in all directions without ever adding columns to your table. 

but implementing that is probably quite a hassle.

Comment: You might want to consider `select concat('1', '.', '2', '.', null);` as well and then think about 20 columns again.

Comment: Yeah when I posted this, the question didn't include the fact that there are 20 digits, and it looked like just 3 or 4 digits. It appears that no one else posted an answer. I, for one, would like to know why anyone would use 20 pieces of a version number. I can't even envision a scenario. But to help, I recommend doing a fixed-width standardized version like @muistooshort posted.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to support versions like `1.1-beta` or using old MySql versions without `INTE_ATON`, you can get the same sort by splitting the version and sorting each part as an integer and string:

```
SELECT
    version,
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 1), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 1 - 1)) + 1), '.', '') v1,
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 2), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 2 - 1)) + 1), '.', '') v2,
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 3), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 3 - 1)) + 1), '.', '') v3,
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 4), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 4 - 1)) + 1), '.', '') v4
FROM 
    versions_table
ORDER BY
    0+v1, v1 DESC, 0+v2, v2 DESC, 0+v3, v3 DESC, 0+v4, v4 DESC;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expressions. First normalize the value:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE('v1.22.333', '^v', ''),
        '(^|\\.)(\\d+)',
        '\\100000\\2'
    ),
    '0+(\\d{5})(\\.|$)',
    '\\1\\2'
)
```

Output:

```
00001.00022.00333
```

Then you can sort normally.

This solution works with any number of components. You can scale component length from 5 to any fixed length.

Comment: With MySQL 8.0.32 I had to use `$` instead of ``\\`` for the back references (e.g. `$1` instead of ``\\1``).

Answer (score 1):

Although, the @TrinitronX answer is pretty elegant, it does not work for the wide range of possible [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) values. In particular those, that consist of the pre-release part like `1.0.0-beta.1`.

Another way is to keep a sorted list of versions in the MySQL database table. Let's create the following database table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `versions` (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    version VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
    sort_order BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY unique_version (version),
    KEY idx_sort_order_version (sort_order)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Every time we add a new version to the `versions` DB table we calculate the `sort_order` value before inserting the record. In theory the complexity of this operation should be O(log n). Having this, we can get the sorted list of versions using the SQL query below:

```sql
SELECT `version` FROM `versions` ORDER BY sort_order;
```

I created the [https://github.com/recipe/mysql-sermver](https://github.com/recipe/mysql-semver) project, to implement this idea in two MySQL stored functions:

##### 1. `VERSION_COMPARE(version1, version2)`

This function supports the Semantic Versioning 2 as well as the most of the real life versions. It returns

- `0` if the both versions are equal,
- `1` if the `version1` is greater than the `version2`,
- `-1` if the `version2` is greater than the `version1`.

```sql
SELECT VERSION_COMPARE('1.0.0', '1.0.0');
0

SELECT VERSION_COMPARE('1.0.2-alpha', '1.0.2');
-1

SELECT VERSION_COMPARE('1.0.2-beta', '1.0.2-alpha');
1
```

##### 2. `GET_SORT_ORDER(version)`

This function calculates the `sort_order` value of a newly added version, and can be used inside the `BEFORE INSERT` database trigger on the `versions` DB table.

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER bi_versions_set_sort_order BEFORE INSERT ON versions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE v BIGINT UNSIGNED;

    IF NEW.sort_order = 0 THEN
        SELECT GET_SORT_ORDER(NEW.version) INTO v;
        SET NEW.sort_order = v;
    END IF;
END //
```

**How it works for the question above?**

You need to install these two stored functions from the [mysql-semver](https://github.com/recipe/mysql-semver) project to your MySQL database. Then you
can add new versions and select them ordered.

```sql
INSERT versions (version, sort_order) 
VALUES
('1.1.2', 0), 
('9.1', 0), 
('2.2', 0), 
('4', 0), 
('1.2.3.4', 0), 
('3.2.14', 0), 
('3.2.1.4.2', 0);

SELECT `version` FROM `versions` ORDER BY sort_order;
+---------+
|version  |
+---------+
|1.1.2    |
|1.2.3.4  |
|2.2      |
|3.2.1.4.2|
|3.2.14   |
|4        |
|9.1      |
+---------+
```

Comment: That is a good project.