# How to order in mysql query based on version like 1.1.0 -> 1.1.1->1.1.2?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]I am retrieving rows from MySQL to a a table in FPDF. this table has
to be ordered by activities that have members (5.3, 5.4.4, 6.6,
11.1.2.3....) these numbers are random. I have tried many ways such as using CAST or order by * 1 but there is always a mistake in the order.

This query is the closest i have come to a correct order, but it is
still incorrect.
have attatched a sample of the result that should show 6.1 at the beginning. However, it starts with 10 [image: sample]

this is my table called pack.

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| budget_hours   | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_description  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bogie_type_id_ | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| skillset       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| budget_mins    | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| activity       | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and this is transactions table

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| activity         | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status           | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name             | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bogie_id         | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bogie_serial_no_ | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duration         | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_timestamp  | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_timestamp    | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
select transaction.activity,  pack.a_description,  transaction.name,
  pack.activity as pa, FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction.end_timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y') as et
from transaction
inner join pack  on pack.activity=transaction.activity
where transaction.bogie_id='$id' and bogie_type_id_='$bt'
order by REPLACE(pa,'.','')  ASC
```

Comment: Please show us column names and structure.

Comment: Also be warned that your SQL query is open for injection. Better use prepared statements

Comment: About how many records are we talking about each time you generate this? 10? 100? 1000? Can it be more than 1000? If the amount isnt that big, then you could fetch all records in arrays/objects and then simply use a [custom sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145393/sorting-a-php-array-of-arrays-by-custom-order) on php side, then you can make the sort as complex as you want.

Comment: The records are over 500, i will look into this approach, thank you. @DefinitelynotRafal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql sorting of version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508313/mysql-sorting-of-version-numbers/8408337)

Comment: I found the code behind this MySQL function to solve my problem INET_ATON. from this previous question on MySQL  sorting of version numbers