# Version number(x.y.z) comparison in SQL query by using regular expression

Tags: sql, regex

I have a SQL database table like below.

| id | version | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0.1 | xxx |
| 2 | 1.1.0 | yyy |
| 3 | 1.1.3 | zzz |
| 4 | 1.10.1 | aaa |
| 5 | 2.0.0 | bbb |

I would like to select the data which `version` is greater than or equal to `1.1.0`.

In above case, the expected output is below.

| id | version | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.1.0 | yyy |
| 3 | 1.1.3 | zzz |
| 4 | 1.10.1 | aaa |
| 5 | 2.0.0 | bbb |

Would you tell me how to extract that in SQL query ??

Comment: Assuming you are talking about MySQL, [this StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508313/mysql-sorting-of-version-numbers) has an accepted answer.

Comment: MSSQL 2016 and higher has [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: If you are using Postgres, you can use `WHERE string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] >= array[1,1,0]`

Answer (score 0):

If your "version string" had nice, fixed-length fields (e.g. "01.10.02") then it's easy.

Since yours doesn't, MSSQL 2016 and higher offers [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Alternatively, this is a great solution that you should be able to use with most RDBMs (including Oracle, MSSLQ and mySql):

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/33560117/421195
>
> ```
> SQL> WITH DATA AS
>   2    ( SELECT 'F/P/O' str FROM dual
>   3    )
>   4  SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1, Instr(str, '/', -1, 1) -1) part1,
>   5         SUBSTR(str, Instr(str, '/', -1, 1) +1) part2
>   6  FROM DATA
>   7  /
>
> PART1 PART2
> ----- -----
> F/P   O
> ```

The example breaks the string into separate columns (e.g. major/middle/minor numbers).

From there, you need to compare the corresponding columns in different rows.

Conceivably, you can do everything in one SQL "select".  In practice, it would probably be easier to write a stored procedure to do one piece at a time.